# Is it possible to run a command after a "pause" in linux desktop?

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal

Is it possible to run a command after a "pause" in linux desktop?  For example:

```
#=========================================================
#NetworkManage Auto Connect:
chkconfig NetworkManager off
echo "service NetworkManager start" >> /etc/rc.d/rc.local
#=========================================================
```

I need to execute a command after networkmanager has connected successfully, and I think the best way to do this is by giving it an 8 second pause.

How can I execute something such as:

```
gedit test.txt
```

about 8 seconds after the command itself has been executed?

Answer (score 2):

NetworkManager has a built-in feature: it can run scripts for you on network up and down events.

You have to place your scripts at:
    /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/

Every script will get two parameters from NetworkManager, the first one is what interface had the event and the second one is the event (up or down).

Example script:

```
#!/bin/bash

INTERFACE=$1 # The interface which is brought up or down
STATUS=$2 # The new state of the interface

echo interface $INTERFACE went $STATUS
```

Comment: i opened a new question about this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16848021/linux-networkmanagers-etc-networkmanager-dispatcher-d-test-script-does-not

Answer (score 1):

Will the `sleep` command do what you need? Like this:

```
sleep 4 && echo 'hello there!'
```

(Waits four seconds, then prints a message)

EDIT: Or for your example,

```
sleep 8 && gedit test.txt
```

Comment: tested this `sleep 8 && gedit test.txt` out by adding it to the bottom of `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` for some reason it did not execute at all after rebooting.

Comment: infact even "gedit test.txt" is not working in that startup file, so nothing is wrong with the command, perhaps this is for a different question ?

Comment: Oh, I'm not an expert but I think you'd need to already have an open terminal to be able to run an editor. You could have rc.local open one like this, perhaps? https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=133065

but @user89709 has a good answer, in that it is probably better not to put a startup process to sleep for 8 seconds on every reboot.

Comment: This might do it though:
`xterm -hold -e "sleep 8 && gedit test.txt"`

Comment: if i run in the desktop manually : `sleep 10 && gedit test.txt` it works, but in the `rc.local` file the only thing that works is `gnome-terminal -e "gedit test.txt"` with sleep it does not work. i tried both `gnome-terminal -e "sleep 10 && gedit text.txt"` as well as `sleep 10 && gnome-terminal -e "gedit test.txt"`